# Ubuntu boot too long (2.5 minutes)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ubuntu-mate

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as my second OS.

When I choose Ubuntu at the boot menu, it takes around 2.5 minutes, whereas Windows 10 boots in around 30 seconds.

Also, when I choose to boot into Ubuntu, GRUB seems like it's glitching up or something because it hangs for 20 seconds or so.

See systemd-analyze screenshots below:

[image: systemd-analyze]

[startup.svg](http://svgur.com/i/39v.svg)

Comment: I rehosted your SVG file at http://svgur.com/i/39v.svg and submitted an edit with that as the link instead so people don't have to worry about downloading and opening a file from an unknown source.

Comment: Have you got fastboot switched on for windows?  i.e. is windows on sda6?  Fastboot does cause issues.  Try switching it off.

Comment: Fast boot is disabled on windows. And Ubuntu is located on sda6.